# How do I just output echo statements?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to JUST output the `echo` commands in the batch file below. However, `icalcs` keeps on putting in its output as well...as there are million of files in the directory I do not want to know what it has worked on but the `echo` statement will tell me where I am at anyway..(or what folder)...

Anyway - I have tried numerous things but in each occasion I am still getting `icacls` printing out its output..

Any ideas?

```
echo off
setlocal
echo Applying Perms on ACL-C-Softlib-L >&2
ICACLS "D:\Apps\Softlib" /GRANT:r "dbg\ACL-C-Softlib-L":(OI)(CI)(X,RD,GR,RC,WD,AD,WEA,GW,DE,DC,RA) /inheritance:e /T /C
echo Applying Perms on ACL-R-Softlib-G >&2
ICACLS "D:\Apps\Softlib" /GRANT:r "dbg\ACL-R-Softlib-G":(OI)(CI)(X,RD,RC,WD,GW,DE,DC,RA) /inheritance:e /T /C
```

Tried the above and running the batch as below but I keep on either getting output on the console (of the things I need) or the log is full of `icacls` stuff...I only want the `echo` statements..

```
softlib_PERMS.cmd 2>>AddAccts.log 2>&1
softlib_PERMS.cmd >nul >AddAccts.log
```

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the output of the ICACLS commands?

Comment: ah - as in echo icacls.... >&2......?and remove all the other echo statements?..hmm..never thought of that - let me try it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by adding `>nul` can help and `@` in `echo off`

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo Applying Perms on ACL-C-Softlib-L
ICACLS "D:\Apps\Softlib" /GRANT:r "dbg\ACL-C-Softlib-L":(OI)(CI)(X,RD,GR,RC,WD,AD,WEA,GW,DE,DC,RA) /inheritance:e /T /C >nul

echo Applying Perms on ACL-R-Softlib-G
ICACLS "D:\Apps\Softlib" /GRANT:r "dbg\ACL-R-Softlib-G":(OI)(CI)(X,RD,RC,WD,GW,DE,DC,RA) /inheritance:e /T /C >nul
```